# Enable app widgets for apps in work profile on COPE enrolled devices

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

We‘d like to configure a policy to allow users to use app widgets in the work profile on fully managed devices with a work profile (aka COPE).

Currently we only see this functionality for work profile apps on device enrolled into work profile on personally-owned devices.

Allow app widget usage on fully managed devices with a work profile in the work perimeter.